# input data into div on login page

Tags: excel, vba

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8d5L.jpg

```
Set IE = New InternetExplorer

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://mdemo.cqg.com/cqg/desktop/logon"
Do While IE.Busy = True: DoEvents: Loop


Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
Set wpfe = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("wpfe-logon-input-full wpfe-native-faded-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid")(0)
wpfe.Value = "User Login"
```

I'm tyring to enter login but it looks like emm... nothing good. Screens of interesting code part and error attached at the top. I hope that you might be able to help.

Comment: What if you execute with F8? what line does arises the error?

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the first input field by the css class names `"wpfe-logon-input-full wpfe-native-faded-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"`. I wrote *names* because every string seperated by a space is an own css class name. The last css class name is not `ng-valid` when you load the page. It's `ng-invalid`. That's the reason for your error.

The solution is to use only the first css class `wpfe-logon-input-full`. But that's not enough to get your goal.

After the first html code was loaded and the IE reports the browser is no more busy, the IE lies to you ;-) There is dynamic content which will be load after that. So you have to wait till that's done.

But even then the login still does not work. You have to trigger two html events per input field.

**This code works:**

```
Sub Login()

  Const url As String = "https://mdemo.cqg.com/cqg/desktop/logon"
  
  Dim ie As Object
  Dim HTMLDoc As Object
  Dim nodeUsername As Object
  Dim nodePassword As Object
  
  Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  ie.Visible = True
  ie.navigate url
  Do While ie.Busy = True: DoEvents: Loop
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5))
  
  Set HTMLDoc = ie.document
  
  Set nodeUsername = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("wpfe-logon-input-full")(0)
  Call TriggerEvent(HTMLDoc, nodeUsername, "compositionstart")
  nodeUsername.Value = "TestName"
  Call TriggerEvent(HTMLDoc, nodeUsername, "compositionend")
  
  Set nodePassword = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("wpfe-logon-input-full")(1)
  Call TriggerEvent(HTMLDoc, nodePassword, "compositionstart")
  nodePassword.Value = "TestPassword"
  Call TriggerEvent(HTMLDoc, nodePassword, "compositionend")
  
  HTMLDoc.getElementByID("login").Click
End Sub
```

**Use this procedure to trigger html events:**

```
Private Sub TriggerEvent(htmlDocument As Object, htmlElementWithEvent As Object, eventType As String)

  Dim theEvent As Object

  htmlElementWithEvent.Focus
  Set theEvent = htmlDocument.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
  theEvent.initEvent eventType, True, False
  htmlElementWithEvent.dispatchEvent theEvent
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you probably meant html classname rather than css. The above is a multi-valued class.

Comment: Class is a fast css selector method and indeed you could single node match rather than index into a collection with HTMLDoc.querySelector(".wpfe-logon-input-full") and  HTMLDoc.querySelector(".wpfe-logon-input-full + .wpfe-logon-input-full") ; though, in this instance, I would probably just use the name attribute in a selector as it is nice and clean to read in the code and benefits from single node match e.g. HTMLDoc.querySelector("[name=loginPassword]")  . OFC, you may wish to not venture too far from original code. I am also wary of using HTMLDoc variable after events; work off ie.document

Comment: @QHarr You are right about the distinction between css and html class names. I'm too vague with the terms. Thanks for the explanation of querySelector() and your thoughts on its use in this particular case. I had never heard of querySelector() before I became active on SO. I think I even read about it for the first time in one of your posts. But I must admit, I haven't worked with it much. But hopefully your thought-provoking input will help me to work with it more in the future.

Comment: It really opens the door on web-scraping with vba. Not as much as non-VBA libraries but certainly enough to do some interesting things. Nice to see you helping people with many web-scraping questions :-)

Comment: Thank you so much. Currently i got another question. If you are able to help i will be greatfull.